# Tkinter pyowm not updating

Tags: python, tkinter, label, auto-update, openweathermap

I have several widgets, or more correctly, `Label`s, that update perfectly when a method finishing with `self.after()`  is called in `__init__.`

That's not the case with this Label here, which gets the weather Information from OWM (OpenWeatherMap) through `pyowm`, and should be updated every specific amount of time, defined in the `after()` function.

I've tried almost everything in my knowledge, though I'm pretty newbie to Python. I've searched google for days, but no working solution was found, or not that I could make it work.
I've tried to put the after function in every method, even `__init__`.

The trimmed down `main()` for debug and the Weather Class follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from Weather import Meteo


def displayMeteo(win):
    # Place Meteo portlet
    meteoHandler = Meteo(win, bg='black', fg='white')
     meteoHandler.pack(side='top', anchor='ne')


def main():
    # Set the screen definition, root window initialization
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background='black')
    width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(),
    root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Monitor Dashboard", bg='black',
                     fg='red')
    label.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', anchor='se')

    # Display portlet
    displayMeteo(root)

    # Loop the GUI manager
    root.mainloop(0)


###############################
#     MAIN SCRIPT BODY PART   #
###############################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the class:

```
import pyowm
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Meteo(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **params):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent)
        self.API = pyowm.OWM('API KEY', config_module=None,
                         language='it', subscription_type=None)
        self.location = self.API.weather_at_place('Rome,IT')
        self.weatherdata = self.location.get_weather()
        self.weather = str(self.weatherdata.get_detailed_status())
        self.dictionary = {'poche nuvole': 'Parzialmente Nuvoloso',
        'cielo sereno': 'Sereno', 'nubi sparse': 'Nuvoloso',
        'temporale con pioggia': 'Temporale', 'pioggia leggera':
        'Pioggerella'}

        self.Display()

def Temperatur(self):
    self.Temp = tk.StringVar()

    self.tempvalue = self.weatherdata.get_temperature('celsius')
    self.temperature = str(self.tempvalue.get('temp'))

    self.Temp.set(self.temperature)
    self.after(3000, self.Temperatur)

def WeatherInfo(self):
    self.Weather = tk.StringVar()

    self.weather = str(self.weatherdata.get_detailed_status())
    if self.weather in self.dictionary:
        self.weather = self.dictionary[self.weather]

    self.weatherstring = self.weather.title()

    self.Weather.set(self.weatherstring)
    self.after(3000, self.WeatherInfo)

def Display(self):
    self.Temperatur()
    self.WeatherInfo()
    self.configure(text=self.Weather.get() + ",   " + self.Temp.get() + "°", bg='black',
                   fg='#FFFF96', font=("arial, 35"))
    self.after(3000, self.Display)
```

Now, what should happen is the widget updating every 3 secs (just to debug), although I know even if updating works it won't change every 3 seconds, 'cause you know...weather doesn't change every 3 secs.

Comment: Not familiar with the API, but are you sure you're getting the refreshed data in each `WeatherInfo()` and `Temperatur()`? It could be that once you have initialized `self.weatherdata` the data is already stagnant.  Try `print`ing out the `get_detailed_status()` to see if they are actually any different in each refresh.  If not, you might need to refresh `self.weatherdata` first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check

Comment: The `tkinter` part works for me, `Label`s updated every 3 sec.

Comment: Thanks, @Idlehands, the problem was, as you pointed out, the variable itself being called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As done in suggestion of [Idlehands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9183344/idlehands) the problem was not in the Label or the updating.
The Code, if written that way, would call `.get_weather` only once, thus creating a stagnating variable. I added a method that updates the pyowm parsing and now evertyhing's working fine!